# whitespace-mode doesn't show the space characters

Tags: init-file, customize, whitespace, whitespace-mode

I need to see the space characters but I can't set it for the life of me.

I went to customize the `Whitespace Display Mapping` and this is what I found. Notice that the mapping for the space is set to be ".". It doens't work of course:

```
INS DEL Character Mapping:
            Char Kind: Value Menu Space
            Char:  
            Vector List:
            INS DEL :
                        Vector Characters:
                        INS DEL Char: .
                        INS
            INS
...
```

I even included this into .emacs

```lisp
(setq whitespace-display-mappings '((space-mark 32 [46])
       (newline-mark 10 [36 10]) (tab-mark 9 [187
      9] [92 9])))
```

Still nothing.

Maybe someone know what is the problem here? I just want the whitespace overlay to show the " " character as a ".".

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: The default behavior of `whitespace-mode` is to show a space as a centered dot character.  Have you tried using `whitespace-mode` without making any modifications?  Try opening any file in `fundamental-mode` and type `M-x whitespace-mode` without any whitespace configuration settings.

Comment: For the record, the visual display of the space-mark it is not an overlay -- it is a glyph that is displayed via the `buffer-display-table`.

Comment: Jenia Ivanov: Does your `whitespace-style` variable contain `space-mark` ? (or if using the customize interface: `(Mark) SPACEs and HARD SPACEs` ?)

Answer (score 1):

Your settings work. Make sure that you don't have grayish window background.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As phils already said in the comments `whitespace-style` needs to include `space-mark`.

See my answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18520/10344) for details.