# Whitespace mode write dots for space chars

Tags: whitespace-mode

I'm using `org-indent-mode`. As far as I understand, the whitespace on the left is an overlay.

[image: org-indent-mode overlay]

When you use this mode in conjunction with `whitespace-mode`, then there appears whitespace indications (dots) in the org-mode overlay on the left.

[image: []2]

Does anyone know how to get rid of it? Specifically, how to get rid of the whitespace markings in the `org-mode-indent`'s overlay?

You might ask yourself, white not remove the whitespace-mode? It's useful in marking the whitepaces in the buffer itself. Like... well I use it quite successfully, I just want to remove it from the damn overlay.

Thanks

P.S. All of this is in emacs vanilla, no other programs than the one's packages by GNU.

The version is: 24.5.1

Comment: In most cases, whitespace visualization is *not* done with overlays, but is instead done with altering the `buffer-display-table`.  See my comment to your prior semi-related post:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14006/2287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customize option `whitespace-display-mappings`, to get rid of this entry:

```
(space-mark   ?\     [?\u00B7]     [?.])        ; space - centered dot
```

That maps a `SPC` char to a centered dot.

```
M-x customize-option RET whitespace-display-mappings RET
```

This is the entry to remove or change, in the Customize UI:

[image]

You can just click the first `DEL` to remove it, if you do not want `SPC` chars mapped to other chars.  (Save your changes when done.)

Comment: Hey man.
This doesn't work. It removed all the whitespace markings. In the buffer and in the overlay.
You see, the whitepsace in `org-indent-mode`, are not in the buffer (it's not in the file) as far as I understand. It's an overlay. I want to make those white spaces - in the overlay - not be marked.

Comment: @Drew -- in a related thread, mentioned in my comment underneath the original question hereinabove, *phils* asked this same original poster about the variable `whitespace-style` and whether it contained **space-mark**.  The original poster never responded to the question by *phils*, but it may be relevant to both questions -- i.e., for this question, the O.P. should *remove* **space-mark**, and for the other question, the original poster should *add* **space-mark**.